# how can I detect if g++ compiled without errors

Tags: linux, scripting

I have a script file to automatically compile a C++ program, then automatically run the executable.

## script

```
g++ -o bin/program main.cpp 
bin/program
```

The problem is, sometimes the compiler encounters an error, and the executable is not generated. Therefor, the script will be running an outdated version.

How can I detect if g++ was unable to generate the executable, so that I may prevent the script from running the file?

Comment: Exit code from `g++` execution?

Comment: how can I check the exit code from g++? @RomeoNinov

Comment: See my answer how to exec the program if `g++` finish with no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the exit code of execution of `g++` like this:

```
g++ -o bin/program main.cpp 
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
then bin/program
fi
```

Comment: Ouch. While this works, this is bad coding style - you should do it like that: `if g++ -o bin/program main.cpp; then ... fi`

Comment: @Martin, `if` in my example is perfectly correct usage. Yes, you can add compilation in `if` but think about the case when your line is 100 chars long. Or more :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file exists first:

```bash
test -x foo && ./foo
```

Comment: won't help if it still exists from a previous successful compilation.

Comment: True if you don't clean it first.